# WSJDBCConnection does not wrap objects of type Oracle jdbc Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere, ojdbc

I am using Websphere liberty server to run my application and I need to use `ArrayDescriptor` for passing arrays to the oracle stored procedure. I get an exception while unwrapping the connection. I have checked the connection meta data driver information as well and it is showing me oracle.jdbc driver. The code fails at connection unwrapping line.

```
Connection conn = this.getDataSource().getConnection();
OracleConnection oracleConn = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
```

> Exception message: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E:
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection@120edaf does not wrap
>   any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.

I have added class loader reference for my application in the server.xml as well but that didn't help.

My server.xml looks like :

```
<dataSource  id="datasource" jndiName="jdbc/XXXXXX" 
type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="ordLib"/>
<properties.oracle databaseName="XXXX" driverType="thin" password="XXXXXX" 
portNumber="XXXXXX" serverName="XXXXXX" serviceName="XXXXXX" url="XXXXXX" 
user="XXXXXX"/>
</dataSource>

<webApplication id="NAExtractWeb" location="NAExtractWeb.war" 
name="NAExtractWeb">
<classloader commonLibraryRef="ordLib"></classloader>
</webApplication>

<library id="ordLib">
    <fileset dir="C:\lib" id="fileset" includes="ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar"/>
</library>
```

Also I use this unwrap function in one of my dependent project jar and I have ojdbc dependency(maven) added in my dependent project. Will that affect the unwrapping step?

Here is the method which will get the data source:

```
 public DataSource getDataSource(String dsName) throws BatchException {

    try {
        return (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup(dsName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            //Code to handle
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

[6/19/18 17:20:29:340 IST] [process partition0] com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger                                     CWWKY0030I: An exception occurred while running the step process.
com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: Failure in Read-Process-Write Loop
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:704)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeCoreStep(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.BaseStepControllerImpl.execute(BaseStepControllerImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ExecutionTransitioner.doExecutionLoop(ExecutionTransitioner.java:118)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeCoreTransitionLoop(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeWorkUnit(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:155)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl$AbstractControllerHelper.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:480)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:89)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.BatchWorkUnit.run(BatchWorkUnit.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection@73c25e77 does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.ItemWriterProxy.open(ItemWriterProxy.java:67)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.openReaderAndWriter(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:954)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:599)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection@73c25e77 does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcWrapper.unwrap(WSJdbcWrapper.java:459)
    at com.fmr.nfiws.batch.writer.DBWriter.open(DBWriter.java:149)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.artifact.proxy.ItemWriterProxy.open(ItemWriterProxy.java:64)
    ... 16 more

Comment: _"I have ojdbc dependency(maven) added in my dependent project"_ this probably means that there are **two** `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` classes on the classpath: one loaded by Websphere itself for the connections created for the pool, and one loaded by your application. If your application references `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class`, that might result in a **different** class, which leads to a failure to unwrap (because they aren't loaded by the same classloader). You might want to check what happens if you explicitly exclude the Oracle dependency from your project.

Comment: The ojdbc dependency jar scope was set to "provided" to not to add it in the build and only for compilation. After adding it the code throws me NoClassDefErro r at unwraaping line..

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?  Perhaps that will give us more ideas.

Comment: Do you have the Oracle driver packaged in your application or otherwise on your classpath in some way (other than the config you have already provided)?

Comment: Yes Alex..I have included the ojdbc dependency in my project and set the scope to provided. Do you want me to remove the dependency completely?. If i try removing it , i am getting a compilation error. so do you know any other way to use only one jar for both compilation and at runtime?

Comment: "adara muthu" is the only solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this on WebSphere Liberty and the following code worked for me:

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/oracle")
private DataSource ds;

// ...

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
OracleConnection oracleConn = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
```

My server.xml looks like this:

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/oracle">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="oracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle URL="${jdbc.URL}" user="${jdbc.user}" password="${jdbc.password}"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="oracleLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/oracle"/>
</library>

<application location="myApp.war" >
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="oracleLib"/>
</application>
```

The important thing to note here is the use of `commonLibraryRef` on the `<classloader>` element.  If you use `privateLibraryRef` it will not work because the app and server-defined datasource will use isolated classloaders to load the Oracle JDBC classes.

If this answer isn't helpful to you, please update your question with your server.xml configuration, and also how you are obtaining an instance of your `DataSource`.

Comment: Can you also include your `<application>` configuration?  that is relevant config for determining the issue

Comment: Added the application tag with the commonLibraryRef pointing to the same ordLib

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this problem here is my solution.

My mistake was that I was deploying my application to the `dropins` folder and if you define an `application/webApplication` in your `server.xml` it is ignored. I deployed it somewhere else, set this new location to the application tag and also added the `<classloader>` in `server.xml`, left the `ojdbc jar` as provided in `pom.xml` and it  works now.

But still I had a problem when I was running the application locally, because the `ojdbc jar` was provided in `pom.xml`.
My solution was to use reflection to get the system class loader and load the jar  at runtime for the local profile.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing in my local machine, but not worked because of same ojdbc jar available in the liberty run time server path. After removing its works fine.
 LibertyRuntime(In project explorer)->
                 servers(choose the deployed server)->
                  apps->you  could see application-name.war.xml(Please remove the ojdbc jar from the xml).

Make sure the jar is not available in the xml file
Finally start the server, It will work.