# WSJdbcConnection does not wrap any objects of type com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, datasource, websphere-liberty, server.xml

I am using **SQLServerBulkCopy** API to store millions of records in SQL Server database. I get an error stating

> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Destination
>   connection must be a connection from Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL
>   Server"

during initializing it like

```
SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy =  new SQLServerBulkCopy(conn);
```

So I unwrapped the connection

```
SQLServerConnection conn = connection.unwrap(SQLServerConnection.class);
```

The original connection is `com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@8da2f3e2`

After going over the following questions previously asked 
1. [WSJDBCConnection does not wrap objects of type Oracle jdbc Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927325/wsjdbcconnection-does-not-wrap-objects-of-type-oracle-jdbc-connection) 
2. [I get the `DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@d3t7e556 does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607238/i-get-the-dsra9122e-com-ibm-ws-rsadapter-jdbc-wsjdbcconnectiond3t7e556-does-n)

I found that it is because of classLoader for sqljdbc42.jar,  mismatch between datasource and the application

So I changed my server.xml like this

```
 <library id="global">
   <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global" includes="*.jar"/>
 </library>

 <jdbcDriver id="SqlJdbcDriver"              
                javax.sql.DataSource = 
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource"
                 libraryRef="global"/>

 <application id="myApp" name="myApp" type="ear" location="myApp.ear">
   <classloader commonLibraryRef="global"/>
 </application>
```

The datasource tag resides in another server.xml that is specific for env by env -

```
<dataSource id="myDS" jdbcDriverRef="SqlJdbcDriver" jndiName="jdbc/myDS">
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="2m" connectionTimeout="2s" maxPoolSize="50" minPoolSize="0" />
    <properties.microsoft.sqlserver databaseName="myDB" serverName="xxx.com" /> 
</dataSource>
```

The sqljdbc42.jar also resides in lib/global dir.
Also, I removed the dropins dir and placed the myApp in apps dir, as the `application` tag will not work if the app the present in dropins dir.

After all these changes too, I get the exception

> "com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@8155ea2d does not wrap any
>   objects of type com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection."

Can anybody figure out what's the solution or what still I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC wrapper pattern, java.sql.Wrapper.unwrap(c), is for unwrapping as interface classes only, not concrete implementation classes.

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection` is an implementation, but fortunately, the Microsoft JDBC Driver also provides an interface for it: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ISQLServerConnection`.

Try unwrapping as the interface,

```
ISQLServerConnection conn = connection.unwrap(ISQLServerConnection.class);
```

Comment: Unwrapping as interface worked. 
But the ISQLServerConnection prints `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy252`
and is not an instance of `SQLServerConnection`, so I get the same exception

    `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Destination connection must be a connection from the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server.`

Also, casting gives `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @GayathriNagarajan It sounds like this `SQLServerBulkCopy` should check for the interface instead of the concrete class. Otherwise you'll need to get a physical connection directly without using a data source from WebSphere. You might want to consider filing a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, physical connection worked! Thanks, and I've opened an issue too at that url.