# Getting an OracleConnection from datasource.getConnection()

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have tried the solution in [WSJDBCConnection does not wrap objects of type Oracle jdbc Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927325/wsjdbcconnection-does-not-wrap-objects-of-type-oracle-jdbc-connection)

but it isn't working so please how do I get the oracle connection out of a tomcat/spring proxy connection pool.

I am using tomcat and a spring datasource and need the oracle connection so I also can pass arrays to my pl/sql

here is my code:

```
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate();
 DataSource ds = getDataSource();
 Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
 OracleConnection oracleConnection=connection.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
```

My exception is (Thrown on the unwrap):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Not a wrapper of oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

When I debug the connection is a:

```
ProxyConnection[PooledConnection[oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4fbe37eb]]
```

The detail from my context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/dbname"
                global="jdbc/dbname"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

From my server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/NPP_npp"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="XYZ"
            password="NICE_SECURE_PASSWORD"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ora-db-dlabnpp.cpp-group.com:1521/devlab_npp.cpp"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
             maxTotal="20" 
              maxIdle="15" 
              minIdle="5"/>
```

The stacktrace

```
  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.unwrap(ProxyConnection.java:87)
     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:119)
     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:79)
     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
     org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
     com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.unwrap(Unknown Source)
     my_project.dao.impl.NppPolicyAcquisitionDAOImpl.createAdditionalDetails(NppPolicyAcquisitionDAOImpl.java:354)
     my_project.dao.impl.NppPolicyAcquisitionDAOImpl.createPolicy(NppPolicyAcquisitionDAOImpl.java:193)
     my_project.service.impl.PolicyAcquisitionServiceImpl.createPolicy(PolicyAcquisitionServiceImpl.java:95)
     my_project.service.rest.PolicyCreationController.createPolicy(PolicyCreationController.java:68)
     my_project.service.rest.PolicyCreationControllerVersionThree.createPolicyVersionThree(PolicyCreationControllerVersionThree.java:95)
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
     my_project.filter.CppCertificateIdFilter.doFilter(CppCertificateIdFilter.java:57)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
     uk.co.cpp.util.spring.web.filter.SpringContextThreadBindingFilter.doFilter(SpringContextThreadBindingFilter.java:60)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you tried the concrete class `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` instead of the interface you are using now? Also can you add the full stack trace so that it is visible where the exception is being thrown from. Finally make sure that your application doesn't contain the oracle drivers, they should be scoped `provided` if you use maven (as those are provided by tomcat due to the JNDI based datasource), if you include them it will not match the class (class identity is based on classname and class loader!).

Comment: @M.Deinum, we are using gradle. The exception is on the unwrap line.

Comment: In your tomcat configuration is there any data sources defined?

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace, it was requested for a reason. Also as stated, regardless of your build system, the oracle jars shouldn't be part of your application. If you do it will result in classcast exceptions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I actually had ojdbc5 in my unwrapped application, no idea how it got there but my colleagues here will know how to fix that :)

Comment: You need to have it available for compilation only, not distribute it in your application. If you do that your `OracleConnection`in your application won't match the `OracleConnection` loaded by Tomcat. Both are in different classloaders and while being the same class, they aren't equal (due to different classloaders) and the thus an `instanceof` check will fail. Leading to these kind of errors.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you make an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the `DataSource` with JNDI in Tomcat. Which means Tomcat manages the driver and loads the classes in one of its classloaders. If you also include the Oralce JDBC Driver in your application, the `unwrap` will fail.

Both `OracleConntection` classes are in different classloaders and while being the same class, they aren't equal (due to different classloaders) and the thus an `instanceof` check will fail. Resulting in the error from the `unwrap` method.

The solution is fairly simply, by excluding the Oracle JDBC driver from your application. You only need it for compilation, at runtime it is provided by the server.

Comment: I had the same problem with Wildfly. To solve the problem, as described in the response, I changed the Oracle JDBC Driver dependency scope to `provided` and added the following configuration for the `maven-war-plugin` (you can also directly add a `MANIFEST.MF` file in `META-INF` folder): `<archive> <manifest> <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries> </manifest> <manifestEntries> <Dependencies>com.oracle.jdbc</Dependencies> </manifestEntries> </archive>`